# Объединения несколько строк в одну

Tags: mysql, объединение, sql

Как получить одну запись из двух записей?

```
CREATE TABLE `teams` (
`id_team` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
PRIMARY KEY (`id_team`)
```

)

```
CREATE TABLE `date_games` (
`id_game` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`datetime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_game`)
```

)

```
CREATE TABLE `games` (
`id_game` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`id_team` INT(5) NOT NULL,
`goals` INT(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

)

Как можно вывести данные в формате:
name(первая команда) | datetime | name(вторая команда)

Записи с полем id_game в теблице games встречается два раза.

Comment: Думаю, будет правильнее объединять не в SQL, а в самом приложении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если вы действительно хотите, ничего не меняя, получить все одним SQL, то вот пример:

```
SELECT t1.name, date_games.datetime, t2.name
FROM date_games

INNER JOIN games AS g1 ON g1.id_game = date_games.id_game
INNER JOIN games AS g2 on g2.id_game = date_games.id_game AND g1.id_team <> g2.id_team
INNER JOIN teams AS t1 on t1.id_team = g1.id_team
INNER JOIN teams AS t2 on t2.id_team = g2.id_team

GROUP BY date_games.id_game;
```

Хотя толк в этом будет, только если вы индексы соответствующие расставите.

Если же в игре могут принимать только две команды, то почему бы не объединить две записи из games в одну? Т.е. будет три поля: `id_game`, `id_first_team`, `id_second_team`.

Тогда от джойна `g2` мы отказываемся, а таблицы `t1` и `t2` джойним по полям `id_first_team` и `id_second_team` соответственно.

Следующий шаг - почему бы не объединить таблицы `games` и `date_games`? Тогда будет всего два джойна.

Если же по каким-то причинам этого делать нельзя, то действительно ли это является причиной? Может быть, можно обойтись и двумя таблицами? Приведите пример, почему нельзя этого сделать и, может быть, я приведу пример реализации, как можно будет обойтись и двумя таблицами.

UPD: еще один вариант:

```
SELECT date_games.*, GROUP_CONCAT(teams.name) AS teams_in_game
FROM date_games

INNER JOIN games ON games.id_game = date_games.id_game
INNER JOIN teams ON teams.id_team = games.id_team;
```

Но здесь придется в коде выделять названия двух команд в GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: Согласен с Вами, что лучше обойтись 2 таблицами.
Структуру брал из http://www.sql.ru/forum/513594/turnirnaya-tablica